# How can I fetch emails on Android?

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to develop an app that fetches emails from a POP3 server that is not Google and I'm facing many problems.
I'm using JavaMail library and following TutorialsPoint tutorial. Their example for pop3 works fine on Eclipse/desktop but when I move the code on Android it never works and I'm frustrated.
In logcat I get all heaps of errors first of which states that

> W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException even though I'm using AsyncTask (probably not correctly).

Is there a way that I can fix the AsyncTask to work correctly?

Also, is there a way that I can do something like this not using a professional app like K-9 Mail?

The code if somebody is interested:

```
 public class FetchPop extends AsyncTask{

    public static void fetch(String pop3Host, String storeType, String user,
                             String password) {
        try {
            // create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            // emailSession.setDebug(true);

            // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

            store.connect(pop3Host, user, password);

            // create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            Log.d("No. messages:", messages.length + ""); //just the number at first


/*for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                writePart(message);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if ("YES".equals(line)) {
                    message.writeTo(System.out);
                } else if ("QUIT".equals(line)) {
                    break;
                }
            }*/
            // close the store and folder objects
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } /*catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/ catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            String host = "pop.gmail.com";// I tried google's pop 
            String mailStoreType = "pop3";
            String username =
                    "myusername";// change accordingly
            String password = "notmyrealpass";// change accordingly

            //Call method fetch
            fetch(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
            Log.d("mytag","done!");
            return null;
        }

    public void GO() {
        doInBackground(null);
    }





    /*
    * This method checks for content-type
    * based on which, it processes and
    * fetches the content of the message
    */
    public static void writePart(Part p) throws Exception {
        if (p instanceof Message)
            //Call methos writeEnvelope
            writeEnvelope((Message) p);

       /* System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("CONTENT-TYPE: " + p.getContentType());*/

        //check if the content is plain text
        if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            System.out.println("This is plain text");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println((String) p.getContent());
        }
        //check if the content has attachment
        else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            System.out.println("This is a Multipart");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            int count = mp.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                writePart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
        }
        //check if the content is a nested message
        else if (p.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
            System.out.println("This is a Nested Message");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            writePart((Part) p.getContent());
        }
        //check if the content is an inline image
        else if (p.isMimeType("image/jpeg")) {
            System.out.println("--------> image/jpeg");
            Object o = p.getContent();

            InputStream x = (InputStream) o;
            // Construct the required byte array
            int i;
            byte[] bArray = new byte[0];
            System.out.println("x.length = " + x.available());
            while ((i = (int) ((InputStream) x).available()) > 0) {
                int result = (int) (((InputStream) x).read(bArray));
                if (result == -1)
                    i=0;
                bArray = new byte[x.available()];

                break;
            }
            FileOutputStream f2 = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/image.jpg");
            f2.write(bArray);
        }
        else if (p.getContentType().contains("image/")) {
            System.out.println("content type" + p.getContentType());
            File f = new File("image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
            com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream test =
                    (com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream) p
                            .getContent();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = test.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        else {
            Object o = p.getContent();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("This is a string");
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
                System.out.println((String) o);
            }
            else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
                System.out.println("This is just an input stream");
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
                InputStream is = (InputStream) o;
                is = (InputStream) o;
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
                    System.out.write(c);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("This is an unknown type");
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
                System.out.println(o.toString());
            }
        }

    }
    /*
    * This method would print FROM,TO and SUBJECT of the message
    */
    public static void writeEnvelope(Message m) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This is the message envelope");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        Address[] a;

        // FROM
        if ((a = m.getFrom()) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
        }

        // TO
        if ((a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
        }

        // SUBJECT
        if (m.getSubject() != null)
            System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + m.getSubject());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the AsyncTask correctly, especially seeing that you have a `GO()` method that directly calls `doInBackground()`.  Remove the `GO()` method, there is no need for it.

The proper way to execute an AsyncTask is to use the `execute()` method, which calls `doInBackground()` and runs it on a worker thread, which will eliminate the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` runtime errors that you are getting currently.

So, in addition to using a library that is specific to Android, fix your AsyncTask so that it actually runs the `doInBackground()` method in a worker thread instead of the main UI thread.

In general it's better practice to use generics and varargs rather than just having `doInBackground()` take a `Object[]` as a parameter.
It would also be useful to be able to pass in the username and password each time you execute the AsyncTask, so make it take a String varargs parameter.

```
public class FetchPop extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String host = "pop.gmail.com";// I tried google's pop 
        String mailStoreType = "pop3";

        String username = params[0]; //passed in through the execute() method      
        String password = params[1]; //passed in through the execute() method

        //Call method fetch
        fetch(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
        Log.d("mytag", "done!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, to properly execute the AsyncTask, use the `execute()` method, and pass in a username and password:

```
 //First get the username and password from the user through the UI
 String user =  "myusername"; // change accordingly
 String pass = "notmyrealpass"; // change accordingly
 new FetchPop().execute(user, pass);
```

Also, note that any UI related code will need to be placed in `onPostExecute()`, since all UI tasks need to be executed on the main UI thread in Android.

For more general info on AsyncTasks, there is a lot of good info in [this question and the answers posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: It worked! I know it's better to pass variables like that. This was just copy paste from TutorialsPoint to get me starting. I will decompose this class in multiple methods for my project now that I know it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this lib https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/.

Don't know the exact status of the lib but they have a good example in this  blog (http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) and they say

> "this is a special version of the JavaMail API, which was written specifically for Android."

Comment: I will definitely try it out. Thanks!